# Only the first object from the Angular array is retrieved

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs

I need your help. I'm practicing Angular and trying to pass data between components using rxjs. I have 2 components and a service. I'm getting data from an API. My code works, but it's not correct.
I manage to get the object from the array and transfer it, but unfortunately, only the first element of the array is extracted. Please tell me how to get different objects by clicking on the button, and not just the first one? Thank you very much

Service

```
export class CheckboxServiceService {

   public allSelectedProducts: BehaviorSubject<ProductModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ProductModel[]>([])

   sendProductToList(product: any) {
      this.allSelectedProducts.next(product);
   }
}
```

ComponentSender

```
export class ProductsListApiComponent implements OnInit {

   products: ProductModel[];
   productDifferent: any;

   constructor(private apiService: ApiService , private checkboxService: CheckboxServiceService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.apiService.getAllProducts().subscribe(value => this.products = value);
   }

   addProductToList() {
      let currentValue = this.checkboxService.allSelectedProducts.getValue();
      this.productDifferent = this.products.find(element => element.id);
      currentValue.push(this.productDifferent);
      this.checkboxService.sendProductToList(currentValue);
   }
}
```

ComponentReceiver

```
export class ProductsRecieverComponent implements OnInit {

    public selectedProductsList: ProductModel[] = [];

    constructor(private checkboxService: CheckboxServiceService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.checkboxService.allSelectedProducts.subscribe(value => {
       this.selectedProductsList = value;
    })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `sendProductToList` method. Indeed, you're only emitting one product, rather than adding a new product to the product list.

```js
sendProductToList(product: any) {
  this.allSelectedProducts.next(product);
}
```

By calling `next` passing a single product, you're always emitting a single product, they won't "accumulate".

Besides that, most times you don't want to expose a `BehaviorSubject` as a public member of your service, but rather an `Observable`, since the first supports read and write operations while the latter is readonly, preventing clients from using your service the wrong way.

Hence, this should fix it.

```js
export class CheckboxService {
  public products$: Observable<Product[]>;
  private productsSubject: BehaviorSubject<Product[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.productsSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this.products$ = this.productsSubject.asObservable();
  }

  sendProductToList(product: Product) {
    const products = this.productsSubject.value;
    const updatedList = [...products, product);
   
    this.productsSubject.next(updatedList);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer, your code doesn't work: I still get when I click on any element only the index of the first object and moreover I get an error in my `ComponentSender` in the line `this.checkboxService.sendProductToList(currentValue);`, the method `addProductToList()`and the error looks like this: `<html>TS2345: Argument of type 'ProductModel[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ProductModel'.<br/>Type 'ProductModel[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ProductModel': id, title, price`

Comment: You have to update your `addProductToList` method. You're passing a list of products to the service's method, but the method expects a single product. That's what the TypeScript error is telling you.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how to fix it. I get the value from subject, I try to search for elements by id (but I get only the first object of any kind). And I send it in the subject. What is my mistake?